# UIImageView is clipping a pixel of the bottom of my UIImage...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm not sure what might be causing this, but `UIImageView` occasionally clips off about a pixel or 2 from the bottom of some square/rectangular `UIImages` I'm using as subviews for `UITableViewCells`. These `UIImageViews` are well within the borders of the cell, so it shouldn't be due to cliptobounds. There seems to be no consistency or pattern to which images are being clipped, nor when they're clipped, other than that it only happens to (or is only noticable in) square/rectangular icons, and only ones that are parented to `UITableViewCells` (or their subclasses). I'm having trouble reproducing the problem consistently, which is why I haven't posted any code this time.

Has anyone encountered something similar to this before?

I've encountered a similar bug that involved floating point values for origin/size being interpreted weirdly... but that doesn't seem to be the cause of this particular problem.

I don't need a specific solution at this point, I'm just making sure I haven't missed any well-known bugs or documented problems that involve UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but strangely enough only with the imageViews in the header cells. The fix in my case was to set the `contentMode` of the image view and everything looked the way you would expect.

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not `UIImageView` is the cause?

If you have an image in UITableViewCell and you don't at least 5 pixels "free space", the  UITableViewCell may not look as it should be.

Try to set the `rowHeight` when you're initializing the table. For ex:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 60;
```

If this does't solve the problem, pls provide mode details.